# Fix UISearchdisplaycontroller searchbar at top of UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a UITableView and UISearchDisplayController but when i scroll tableview the searchbar also scrolls along with it. To overcome this i moved UISearchDisplayController searchbar outside UITableView and now my layout is as below, also adjusted the searchbar y position to 65 & corresponding adjusted height of tableview

```
View
  -> SearchBar
  -> TableView
       -> ContentListCell
```

After moving out searchbar, when i start searching the searchbar moves above and its not seen. 
How can i fix the issue? I want to keep the searchbar at the top position.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the UISearchbar to move up when becoming active, you can set the property displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar to NO for UISearchDisplayController.

Comment: After setting the displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar property to NO on selecting search button from search results hides the search bar.

Comment: I've had some previous problems with searchBar and UISearchDisplayController in iOS 7. This might not be such a pretty solution, but I solved it by solely using the UISearchBar, and providing my own TableView for displaying results. Otherwise, I've had to add the searchbar as the TableView's HeaderView to make it work correctly, but then of course it'll scroll with the TableView.